# How to hide login credentials in log.html file in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have tried using `--removekeywords name:Login(keyword)` in the command line but the `log.html` file doesn't hide the keyword.

Can anyone please help me out at least to flatten the `Login` keyword in `log.html` file

Comment: Are you literally using `--removekeywords name:Login(keyword)`? Is  your keyword literally named `Login(keyword)`? That's a highly unusual name for a keyword.

Comment: No no I mean to say that Login was the Keyword name, the keyword I am using is Login

Comment: You need to show the _exact_  command line option you're using.

Comment: robot  --removekeywords name:Login  -V Maps\Map\Variable.yaml Maps\Tests\Maps_Testcases.robot   this is command I am using to hide the keyword

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the new information rather than burying it in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. will find another source to get the answer for this question.

Comment: This is probably the best place to get an answer to your question. It's just that we need more information. You're saying something doesn't work when it is known to work, but you aren't showing us an example.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to hide credentials, there are two things you should do. First, make sure the credentials are stored in variables rather than hard-coded in the call to the `Login` keyword.

Second, use `--removekeywords` to remove the `Login` keyword from the log and report files. Note that the name you give to `--removekeywords` must match the full name of the keyword.

For example, let's imagine you have a resource file named `Keywords.robot` that defines your `Login` keyword:

```
# Keywords.robot
*** Keywords ***
Login
    [Arguments]  ${username}  ${password}
    log  your super secret password is ${password}
```

Now, consider a test case that uses this keyword:

```
# example.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource  Keywords.robot

*** Variables ***
${Username}  somebody@example.com
${Password}  SuperSecret!

*** Test cases ***
Example
    do something
    login  ${username}  ${password}
    do something else
```

If you do *not* use `--removekeywords`, the log will show this:

[image]

If you use `--removekeywords  NAME:Keywords.Login` then you will see this:

[image]

Comment: My sincere apologies, for making such comment. But you are gem of a man, this solution has worked for me. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom keyword for all sensitive inputs which will work just as "Input Text" (selenium library) accepting the same arguments but not logging into output.xml

```
Sensitive Input
   Set Log Level    NONE
   [Arguments]  ${locator}  ${value}
   Input Text  ${locator}  ${value}
   Set Log Level    INFO
```

Comment: I would recommend using `${old_log_level}  Set Log Level    NONE` and later in the code restore the level back to previous value using the same keyword. The keyword `Set Log Level` returns hopefully previous value, cause there is no Get Log Level in Robot framework.